# Column based layout with cell spanning multi pages

Tags: tables, two-column

I want create a layout which looks like this (porting a document from Word to LaTeX):

[image: Multi column layout - Word]

I tried to use a table to implement this, but the problem is that the text for 'Attr6' can span multiple pages.
As far as I understand this is not possible with tables, even with longtable .

Another approach was to use *multicols*:

```
\begin{mutlicols}{2}
    Attr6: \columnbreak
    Value6
\end{multicols}
```

But the problem with this solutions is that a muli-page text looks like:

```
Attr6:                 Value6
                       ...more text
------ <page break> ------------

...text continued
on the left column...
```

What else can I use to create this 2 column layout ?

Comment: it looks like a list to me. Use `\begin{description}...\item[Attr5] zz.....`   so the information can be entred without error, worry about the styling later

Comment: I may have said that before:-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=better+set+as+a+list

Answer (score 3):

This is a possible solution with an `enumitem` list inside a breakable `tcolorbox`. The `enumitem` list defines a counter like `Attr?` with a certain `labelwidth` which is also used to fill the background rectangle in `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners, enhanced, breakable,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[red!30] (frame.north west) rectangle ([xshift=2cm]frame.south west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}]
\begin{enumerate}[label=Attr\arabic*,  labelwidth=2cm, labelindent=0pt, leftmargin=2cm, align=left]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[5]
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]